# R does not return any values in Console when using pipes function

Tags: r, pipe

I am trying to complete this pipe function and R is not returning any values in the Console, it just keeps repeating the code. Not sure what I am doing incorrectly? I have already installed the tidyverse package and library as well as the dplyr package and library.

This is the R-Script:

```
filtered_toothgrowth <- ToothGrowth %>%
   filter(dose == 0.5) %>%
   group_by(supp) %>% 
   arrange(len)
```

The Console is just repeating the code:

```
> filtered_toothgrowth <- ToothGrowth %>%
+   filter(dose == 0.5) %>%
+   group_by(supp) %>% 
+   arrange(len)
> 
> filtered_toothgrowth <- ToothGrowth %>%
+   filter(dose == 0.5) %>%
+   group_by(supp) %>% 
+   arrange(len)
> 
> filtered_toothgrowth <- ToothGrowth %>%
+   filter(dose == 0.5) %>%
+   group_by(supp) %>% 
+   arrange(len)
>
```

Comment: You're assigning the results to `filtered_toothgrowth`. If you remove `filtered_toothgrowth <-` or run just `filtered_toothgrowth` after assigning it will print the results in the console

Comment: Thank you! It was driving me mad. Starting learning R and getting to know the ropes. So much appreciated. :)